# Android Layout & overlapping issue

Tags: android, android-layout

[image: layout image]

The image is what i'm trying to achieve. I tried using tab layout, relativelayout and linearlayout (and even a combination), but in no scenario i got it exactly right.

The requirements:

- no overlapping of any component
- no clipping of the image in the button (the green one)
- the red bar is always at the bottom
- in landscape, the components should still be in their same place, but you can scroll down

If required I can paste my current variations of the different layouts, but they are all rather big and messy.

Professional insights on which layout approach you would use is also appreciated, at least i can keep trying using the right things then.

At the moment, the orange things are normal buttons, defined like so:

```
<Button
android:id="@+id/btn_web"
style="@style/NewButton2"
android:onClick="webClick"
android:text="@string/Text_Web"
android:drawableTop="@drawable/jc_menu_web"
android:layout_weight="0.3"

/>
```

This is a problem on its own,because if you stretch the buttons using fill_parent, the result is that the image will be high at the top, whereas the text will be entirely at the bottom.Would be nicer if it were a centered image in the button.